# How to declare extra modules (static files) in python dash app hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, plotly-dash

I am trying to run a python dash app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk service but it is missing the css, and the folder in which I have csv's as data to give results.

I could only declare one static folders but my directory looks like this.

My folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a configuration file to configure static file paths and directory locations using configuration options. You can add a configuration file to your application's source bundle and deploy it during environment creation or a later deployment.

If your environment uses a platform branch based on Amazon Linux 2, use the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles` namespace.

The following example configuration file tells the proxy server to serve files in the `statichtml` folder at the path `/html`, and files in the `staticimages` folder at the path `/images`.

**Example .ebextensions/static-files.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /html: statichtml
    /images: staticimages
```

More information can be found here: [Elastic BeanStalk - Serving static files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-staticfiles.html).